# OAuth and Dropbox api

Tags: authentication, oauth, dropbox-api

I'm trying to use the API dropbox.

Once the authentication window is opened, a message is displayed:

> This session has expired. Please return to the app to try again.

[image: Request error]

[See full image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UaM6V.png)

I'm using a library to work with OAuth called [jsOAuth](https://github.com/bytespider/jsOAuth)

**Console Error**

[image: Error]

[See full image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8yTyq.png)

I published this application: [Here the full code](http://ridermansb.kodingen.com/Rest-JSOAuth.html)

### Notes

- I know that is not very safe to use OAuth with Javascript, but this is only for studying the OAuth standard.
- [See here the complete JS](http://ridermansb.kodingen.com/scripts.js)
- Any example of using javascript with OAuth will help me a lot

**Thank you all for your help!**

Answer (score 2):

That error message means the request token used for that authentication session is no longer valid, likely because a timeout has passed. (The request token is only good for a certain amount of time.) You need to start over with a new request token.